# C (Linux): warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: c

I have the following snippet that gives me a warning when compiling (the code works anyway):

```
char *x_first_name, *x_last_name, *x_address, *x_zip;

const size_t firsts_count = sizeof(firsts) / sizeof(firsts[0]);
const size_t lasts_count = sizeof(lasts) / sizeof(lasts[0]);
const size_t streets_count = sizeof(streets) / sizeof(streets[0]);
const size_t zips_count = sizeof(zips) / sizeof(zips[0]);

srand(time(NULL));

x_first_name = firsts[rand() % firsts_count]; // line 69
x_last_name = lasts[rand() % lasts_count]; // line 70
x_address = streets[rand() % streets_count]; // line 71
x_zip = zips[rand() % zips_count]; // line 72
```

Warning compiling:

```
authorize.c: In function 'main':
authorize.c:69: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
authorize.c:70: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
authorize.c:71: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
authorize.c:72: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

firsts, lasts, streets and zips are declared as:

```
const char *firsts[] = {
        "Asgar",
        "Aadit",
        "Aanand",
        "Aaron"
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown the definitions for `firsts`, `lasts`, etc.  By the looks of the error they include `const`, whereas `x_first_name` does not.

Comment: How are `firsts`, `lasts` `streets` and `zips` declared?

Comment: Also, expect to be hassled about using `rand() % k`.

Comment: Yeah, problem was "const char*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the compiler states, you're discarding a qualifier (`const` in this case) from a pointer upon assignment.

This happens when you assign a `char *` the value of a `const char *`.

Answer (score 1):

firsts, lasts,streets are array so operation like `firsts[rand() % firsts_count];` will return a value which is const char* in your case.

But you are trying to collect these values in x_first_name and x_last_name variables which are `char*`(pointer to char).so in assignment it is loosing its const nature.

Comment: Yes, I got it, I will use just "char*", I forgot I defined those arrays in my headers as "const char*", I looked only in the main code and overlooked the header files.